# Amazon S3 - Generating an expiring link using Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I'm trying to create an expiring link to allow access to a private file on S3 using Ruby (1.9.3).

I've been following the instructions from here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#RESTAuthenticationQueryStringAuth - However the final values that I'm getting are wrong. The example only gives the final result, not the values from each step, so I'm not sure where this is going wrong. The intermediate values should be the same regardless of implementation.

The Ruby code that I'm using (including the same key and expires from the above link):

```
require "cgi"
require "base64"
require "openssl"
require "digest/sha1"

key_id = 'AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE' # Example Amazon key id and secret key
key = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY'
expires = 1141889120
string_to_sign =  "GET\n\n\n#{expires.to_s}\n/johnsmith/photos/puppy.jpg"

digest = OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new("sha1"), key, string_to_sign)
base64 = Base64.encode64(digest).strip
signature = CGI::escape(base64)

puts "Digest: #{digest}"
puts "Base64: #{base64}"
puts "Signature: #{signature}"
```

Outputs:

- Digest: }'\n\x18p\x83#CX\xE4N\xC2b\x9FUs\xC5J1\xB6
- Base64: fScKGHCDI0NY5E7CYp9Vc8VKMbY=
- Signature: fScKGHCDI0NY5E7CYp9Vc8VKMbY%3D

However the signature on the Amazon page is: NpgCjnDzrM%2BWFzoENXmpNDUsSn8%3D

Any ideas on where this is going wrong?

Comment: Is that .strip necessary?

Comment: And the Amazon example ensures the string is utf8 encoded too.

Comment: The amazon extample is using a different expires to you - 1175139620

Comment: The .strip is removing a \n - probably not necessary, but doesn't seem to change the result.

Comment: @FrederickCheung - Thanks, that was the issue. Changing the time gives me the correct final value - I've been looking at multiple examples and have combined them. Well that's embarrassing. I'll go test in my own URLs :) Thanks for your help :)